# Call function only in specific state in React with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to using React Hooks and was wondering if it was possible to have useEffect() fire only for specific values of state. Basically I have a simple tic tac toe game and I want the function I have to handle the CPU's turn be called after the human player has made their turn, in other words to essentially call handleCPUTurn() after handleClick() completes the new render.

From what I have already tried, I can either get handleCPUTurn to just once, or infinitely until the game ends. below is the code I have relating to handling turns.

```
const Game = () => {
const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0);
const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);



const handleCPUTurn = () => {
    const pointInHistory = history.slice(0, stepNumber + 1);
    const current = pointInHistory[stepNumber];
    const squares = [...current];
    let randomSqaure = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

    if (calculateWinner(squares)) return;
    
    while(true){
        if (squares[randomSqaure]) {
            randomSqaure = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            continue;
        }
        else {
            squares[randomSqaure] = 'O';
            setHistory([...pointInHistory, squares]);
            setStepNumber(pointInHistory.length);
            setXIsNext(xIsNext);
            break;
        }
    }
}

const handleClick = (i) => {
    const pointInHistory = history.slice(0, stepNumber + 1);
    const current = pointInHistory[stepNumber];
    const squares = [...current];
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = 'X';
    setHistory([...pointInHistory, squares]);
    setStepNumber(pointInHistory.length);
    setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
}
useEffect(() => (
    handleCPUTurn(),[xIsNext]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by a condition inside `useEffect`. As I can see you are already passing `xIsNext` as the dependency in `useEffect`. So it will call every time when value of `xIsNext` changes.

What you can do is: **PUT A CONDITION**

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (!xIsNext) {
    handleCPUTurn();
 }     
} ,[xIsNext]);
```

This will run `handleCPUTurn` only when `xIsNext=false`